# rEFInd won't show mac os or windows

Tags: mac-mini, efi

I have a late 2014 mac mini on mac OS Catalina. I installed rEFInd on it, and when I restarted it, it showed the rEFInd logo, but nothing else. Can someone help me? I really want to keep using my mac mini.

Comment: What is your question? Are you trying to boot back to macOS? If so, restart the mac and hold down the option key until the Startup Manager icons appear.

Comment: I assume that worked? Why did you install rEFInd?